# $A=\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n a_ke^{kx}:a_k\in\mathbb R, n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ is dense in $C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I need to prove that $$A=\displaystyle\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n a_ke^{kx}:a_k\in\mathbb R, n\in\mathbb N\right\}$$ is dense in $C[a,b]$. I had in mind to use the Stone–Weierstrass' theorem, I know that $A$ is an algebra that separates points, but we also need $A$ to contain non-null constants which is extremely complicated for me or at least I can't see the way. I have also tried to prove the density directly, but fall to prove that every polynomial can be uniformly approximated by elements of $A$. Any ideas?

Comment: Surely setting $k=0$ will give you the extremely complicated constants?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, of course I thought about it at the beginning, but the problem explicitly says that the $k's$ are natural numbers $=$ positive integers.

Comment: Ithink you wanted to write $n\in\mathbb N$ and not $k\in\mathbb N$ in your question. $k$ is dummy variable.

Comment: @Gary You are right

Comment: Pretty sure $\{ 1, e^x, \dots e^{nx}\} $ is a linearly independent set, so $A$ will not contain any non-zero constant functions.

Comment: That just means that you can't use Stone Weierstrass, which is a sufficient condition.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes. That is what I am saying ...

Comment: @DionelJaime Yes, but trying to do the density directly is something I don't know where to start.

Comment: If you rescale the parameter using $\log$ you can express it as a problem of polynomials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you probably noticed, we have that
$$ B = \left\{ \sum_{k=0}^n a_k e^{kx} : a_k \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}_0 \right\} $$
is dense in $C[a, b]$, thanks to the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. This easily implies the density of $A$, as follows.

Let $f(x) \in C[a, b]$, and let $p_i(x) \in B$ be elements such that $p_i(x) \to f(x)/e^x$ uniformly, which exists as $B$ is dense. Then $e^xp_i(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly, as $e^x$ is bounded in $C[a, b]$. Now, if $p_i(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k e^{kx}$ is in $B$, then $e^xp_i(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_{k-1}e^{kx}$ is in $A$. This proves that $A$ is dense, as required.

Comment: Good was always before my eyes and I couldn't see it, thank you so much.

Comment: You should write $e^x$ in place of $e^{kx}$ in several places.

Comment: Whooops, you're right! I think it should be correct now.

Comment: +1 Nice. I have seen this trick many times and continue to forget it.

Comment: Perhaps you could also write $p_n$ in place of $p_i$.